# Closing an HTML datalist dropdown on enter

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

I have a datalist I'm using to select items from a list. I would like the datalist dropdown to close when:

1. The user types the exact name of an options and presses enter, or
2. The user clicks on an item in the datalist dropdown.

Both Firefox and Chrome support (2). Firefox also supports pressing enter to close the dropdown. However, typing the option and pressing enter does *not* close the dropdown in Chrome.

Is it possible to Firefox's behavior in Chrome, using Javascript if necessary?

My only idea was to `blur` the datalist input, but the dropdown stayed open in Chrome.

I'm running Firefox 68 and Chrome 75 if that's relevant.

Comment: Are you find the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this today.  Your idea was close, what worked for me in Chrome 80, was to `blur` the input.

```html
<input type="list" id="itemInput" list="itemList"/>
<datalist id="itemList">
  <option value="item1"/>
  <option value="item2"/>
  <option value="item3"/>
</datalist>
```

```js
function selectedOption(value) {
  let selected;
// see if there a matching item, ignoring case
  itemList.childNodes.forEach(function(option) {
    if (option.value.toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase())
      selected = option;
  });
  return selected;
}

itemInput.addEventListener('keypress', function(ev) {
  if (ev.key === 'Enter') {
    const text = itemInput.value;
    const selected = selectedOption(text);
    if (selected) {
// we may have matched on different insensitive case, so set the actual value
      itemInput.value = selected.value;
// blur the input to close the datalist popup
      itemInput.blur();
    }
  }
});
```